# Probability extraction from random forest classifier

Tags: probability, classification, conditional-probability, random-forest

I have a random forest to perform classification. I need the real probability of the predicted class.

They take a feature vector **X** and output a predicted class **C**. Additionally we can compute the confidence level **L** we have over the predicted class (my implementation calls that value PROBABILITY (I'm using OpenCV machine learning module) and it comes by returning the percentage of trees who voted for that particular class, say 80% of the trees voted for class C1 then L is 0.8)

- How can we relate the value **L** or 'Probability' to the real probability of C given the feature vector X?
- Can we simply use **L** as a reliable probability measurement?
- Are the classifier performance values (true/false positive rate, etc) somehow considered into the value **L**, or do I need to use **L** as a prior estimate to compute the real probability given the classifier performance parameters?

Comment: You need to calibrate your model, this is a good starting point reference: http://people.dsv.su.se/~henke/papers/bostrom08b.pdf